# Do different weapon types have different reach?

Tags: diablo-iii

Do different weapon types have different reach? e.g. if I use a regular attack with a polearm, will I be able to strike enemies further away than if I use a regular attack with a dagger?

And if so, what is the reach range of each weapon?

This question is inspired by the behavior in Diablo II as well as [the category header for polearms in Diablo III's official game guide](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/polearm/):

> Any polearm will extend the reach of its wielder’s arms noticeably, allowing them to fight foes from slightly farther away.

I cannot tell, however, if it's just flavor text or has an actual gameplay impact

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In diablo 2 there was melee range attribute on melee weapons,a part in diablo 3 guide indicates that polearms have longer range...However testing in game all weapons appeared to have **same range**.

Most likely another attempt to balance the game.

Answer (score 1):

There was a noticeable gameplay impact with weapon reach in Diablo II. I've noticed the same impact in Diablo III. In general though, weapon reach importance varies depending on your play style.

In a strictly melee playstyle, weapon reach will determine the 'radius' of your 'circle of death'. I much prefer a higher attack speed w/ a crowd control skill in these instances. However, when ranged damage dealers arrive, a melee character must chase down a fleeing ranged enemy, thus making a longer reach weapon  more useful: The chase is shorter because the weapon reach will pick up some of the distance. Since the longer reach weapons usually have higher single-smack damage, the fleeing enemy will usually pause slightly for hit recovery, thus almost always ensuring followup strikes.

If your melee character is highly mobile or has a high movement speed, weapon reach takes second chair to an increased attack speed.

Obviously, this does not apply to ranged damage characters.

In my opinion, higher attack speed is key: Since crowd control is going to be used ANYWAYS... one may as well benefit from applying damage constantly (more enemy hit recovery) and triggering more 'per hit/strike/kill' effects.

Spoken as a DI, DII, and current DIII player that plays both melee and ranged characters. Playing a dual wielding Barb now... dos daggers :)