# What is the range of a melee attack?

Tags: diablo-iii

What is the range, [in yards](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/66058/122), in which you can perform a melee attack? Not including, of course, stuff like [Deadly Reach](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/monk/active/deadly-reach).

(it is my understanding that [weapon type does not matter](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/66107/122))

Comment: Do you mean a non-skill, basic attack?

Comment: Maybe click a static enemy like the Crows Nest thing, and screenshot how far away you are when you stop and swing your weapon, then compare screenshot with [this awesome image](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/66058/8462)?

Comment: @OrigamiRobot well not necessarily, I'm guessing most melee attack skills share the same range as non-skill melee attacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am almost certain the range is 8 yards.  I remember reading this somewhere, and upon testing this and comparing the range of melee to that of skills with know range, I found it to be accurate.  I further compared it to the image in the post referred to by the question, and found that my test results matched the 8 yard mark on that image very closely.