# Does Diablo 3 weapon length increase the engagement distance?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do different weapon types have different reach?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66107/do-different-weapon-types-have-different-reach)

When playing a monk, many of the weapons are clearly for very close range (e.g., the various brass knuckle equivalents).  Some other weapons available to the monk are obviously longer (e.g., a bo staff).

Does the weapon length increase the engagement distance?  Will I likely get a hit on the target before they can reach me?

Comment: This was very true for d2, the Barbarian's whirlwind distance for example was affected by type of weapon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The range of your attacks is only affected by the range of the skill you are using. A bo staff will not increase your range, same goes for other classes.

It's especially obvious for the monk, since he usually attacks with his fists despite the difference in weapons you can equip.